# Open source ready-to-use computer vision to tell whether a picture shows a dog/car/etc

Tags: open-source, document-management, computer-vision, image-recognition, classification

I have a million pictures, and need to categorize them with keywords.

*Example: A picture of a dog driving a car near the Eiffel Tower would get the keywords "dog" and "car" and "eiffel tower".*

Requirements:

- No programming required. Just install a package and it is usable directly via command line or HTTP API.
- No need to "train" it, the software already includes the results of the training.
- Runs on Linux or Mac or Windows.
- 100% open source (training data and training software do not have to be open source, but the final software including data resulting from the training must be open source)
- The objects to recognize are objects frequently seen by humans (*dog*), types of landscapes (*forest*), famous places (*Eiffel Tower*). The more the better, bonus for also including other types of concepts such as famous people (*Nelson Mandela*).
- Super-bonus if the keywords are Wikidata objects (*dog → https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q144*)
- Bonus for providing a probability with each keyword *(97% chances that this picture shows a dog)*

Answer (score 1):

On the Tensorflow Github site there are [pretrained models](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models), some of which are based on Image collections. I think with some digging you'll find more.

Here is one available as a NodeJS model: [MobileNet](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/mobilenet) - Classify images with labels from the [ImageNet](http://www.image-net.org/) database.

```
`npm i @tensorflow-models/mobilenet`
```

I haven't used it personally though. A while back, at a  Meetup, I've seen a talk by someone else using such pretrained models, with Python.